# How do I get the location of the entry module in python?

Tags: python, configparser

I know I can use `__file__` and `os.path.*` to figure out the path of the current module. What about the entry module?

I'm trying to load an ini file into ConfigParser from a module based on the hostname, but I want it to be relative to the entry assembly, not necessarily the working directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *entry module* you mean the program's **entrypoint** this is usually `sys.argv[0]`. So you could do something like this:

**Example:**

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    basedir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    print "base directory: {0:s}".format(basedir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```